# How to effectively color pixels in a BufferedImage?

Tags: java

I'm using the following piece of code to iterate over all pixels in an image and draw a red 1x1 square over the pixels that are within a certain RGB-tolerance. I guess there is a more efficient way to do this? Any ideas appreciated. (`bi` is a `BufferedImage` and `g2` is a `Graphics2D` with its color set to `Color.RED`).

```
    Color targetColor = new Color(selectedRGB);

    for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {
            Color pixelColor = new Color(bi.getRGB(x, y));
            if (withinTolerance(pixelColor, targetColor)) {
                g2.drawRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

private boolean withinTolerance(Color pixelColor, Color targetColor) {
    int pixelRed = pixelColor.getRed();
    int pixelGreen = pixelColor.getGreen();
    int pixelBlue = pixelColor.getBlue();

    int targetRed = targetColor.getRed();
    int targetGreen = targetColor.getGreen();
    int targetBlue = targetColor.getBlue();

    return (((pixelRed >= targetRed - tolRed) && (pixelRed <= targetRed + tolRed)) &&
            ((pixelGreen >= targetGreen - tolGreen) && (pixelGreen <= targetGreen + tolGreen)) &&
            ((pixelBlue >= targetBlue - tolBlue) && (pixelBlue <= targetBlue + tolBlue)));
}
```

Comment: @Ed Taylor: by all mean, do now create a *new Color* for every single pixel of your image: this is precisely how people kill perfs of Java programs.  For a 1920x1200 picture you'd be creating more than 2 million Color objects.  Quite a waste (I know, I know, short lived object, but still: if you can trivially dodge creating 2 millions objects in a split-second, by all mean dodge it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (withinTolerance(pixelColor, targetColor)) {
    bi.setRGB( x, y, 0xFFFF0000 )
}
```

`BufferedImage`'s `setRGB` method's third parameter, as explained in the Javadoc, takes a pixel of the `TYPE_INT_ARGB` form.

- 8 bits for the alpha (FF here, fully opaque)
- 8 bits for the red component (FF here, fully flashy red)
- 8 bits for the green component (0, no green)
- 8 bits for the blue component.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see any red pixels after running the algorithm with setRGB instead, not even after calling repaint(). Maybe this is trivial... I'll investigate this further tomorrow.

Comment: Problem solved, I forgot to update a reference to the new image before repainting. The setRGB method works, but I can't see any considerable performance improvement.