# Why is the proxy pattern so slow?

Tags: java, proxy-pattern

At least in java, the proxy pattern has a lot of overhead - I don't remember the exact figures, but when wrapping tiny methods the proxy takes something like 50 times as long as the wrapped method. This is, for example, why `java.awt.image.BufferedImage.setRGB`&`getRGB` are *really* slow; there's about three proxies wrapping the actual `byte[]`.

Why *50 times*?! Why doesn't the proxy just double the time?

---

Edit: =(

As seems usual for SO, I got a bunch of answers telling me that my question was wrong. It's not. Check out BufferedImage, or some other real proxy pattern, not those microbenchmarks. In fact, if you have to do a lot of pixel manipulation of a BufferedImage and you know its structure, you can achieve said enormous speedups by manually undoing the proxying; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946501/how-to-effectively-color-pixels-in-a-bufferedimage/2946711#2946711).

Oh, and [here's](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/07/19/debunking-myths-proxies-impact-performance/) my source for 50x. As the article details, proxies don't have a noticeable penalty when what they wrap takes a long time, **but** they do have major painful overhead if you're wrapping a tiny method.

Comment: how did you come up with that "50 times" figure? can you demonstrate that?

Comment: *"I don't remember the exact figures, but when wrapping tiny methods the proxy takes something like 50 times as long as the wrapped method."* Sorry, you'll need to cite a reference for that. Sounds like you're repeating some Java hater's FUD otherwise.

Comment: I've read somewhere that Java Proxy is fifty times _FASTER_ than native code.  There!  Problem solved.

Comment: I would prefer if you'd edit your question to remove this hypothetical 50x factor.

Comment: @Vuntic: Having a go at (and apparently romping through and mass-downvoting) people trying to address the question you asked is childish, to put it kindly. You've taken one specific proxy and drawn a completely erroneous conclusion from it. I'm sorry if you don't like that being pointed out to you.

Comment: @tj: I only downvoted the answers that were plain wrong. No, I've taken the authority of a core developer of Spring, plus one specific example.

Comment: @vuntic: **AND** you've misrepresented that that article says. Note: *"Before we go on let's first realize that the overhead that's being added here is fixed. It is definitely **not** the case that if the doIt() method itself would take 5 seconds, the proxied invocation would take 50 times as long. No, instead, the invocation would take 5 seconds + ~500 nanoseconds."* *(his emphasis, not mine)*

Comment: @Vuntic: Okay. My results don't show anything like that for wrapping a tiny method. But surely the article answered the question anyway, as least as it related to the code and scenarios in the article to which that multiplier applied.

Comment: The methods in T.J. Crowder's example, below, *are* tiny, by nearly any definition of "tiny" that you can proffer. His timings pretty much tell the whole story.

Comment: If you're going to make a claim that a dynamic proxy is 50 times slower than "regular" code, the onus is on you, the claimant, to back up the claim. You assert that the article you cite backs up your claim, but it does *not* actually back up your claim, as T.J. Crowder pointed out. The first thing you can do is define exactly what you mean by "tiny." Next, do some local research (write some code, run some tests), to try to come up with an example that backs up your claim. People with **lots** of Java experience find the 50x claim hard to swallow. You can't just handwave that away. Convince us.

Comment: Please note your source is for Dynamic Proxies that use reflection. It's not for just proxying a class. 

Also please note that there are many ways of proxying classes.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know where that "50 times" figure comes from, but it's pretty suspect. It may be that *a specific proxy* is markedly slower than what it's proxying, depending on what each of them is doing, but to generalize from that to say that "the proxy pattern is so slow" is to take a very dramatic and highly-questionable leap in logic.

Try this:

`Thingy.java`:

```
public class Thingy
{
    public int foo(int param1, int param2)
    {
        return param2 - param1;
    }
}
```

`ThingyProxy.java`:

```
public class ThingyProxy
{
    Thingy thingy;

    public ThingyProxy()
    {
        this.thingy = new Thingy();
    }

    public int foo(int param1, int param2)
    {
        return this.thingy.foo(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

`WithoutProxy.java`:

```
public class WithoutProxy
{
    public static final void main(String[] args)
    {
        Thingy t;
        int sum;
        int counter;
        int loops;

        sum = 0;
        t = new Thingy();
        for (loops = 0; loops < 300000000; ++loops) {
            sum = 0;
            for (counter = 0; counter < 100000000; ++counter) {
                sum += t.foo(1, 2);
            }
            if (sum != 100000000) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

`WithProxy.java`:

```
public class WithProxy
{
    public static final void main(String[] args)
    {
        ThingyProxy t;
        int sum;
        int counter;
        int loops;

        sum = 0;
        t = new ThingyProxy();
        for (loops = 0; loops < 300000000; ++loops) {
            sum = 0;
            for (counter = 0; counter < 100000000; ++counter) {
                sum += t.foo(1, 2);
            }
            if (sum != 100000000) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Simple trials on my machine:

```
$ time java WithoutProxy 

real    0m0.894s
user    0m0.900s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time java WithProxy

real    0m0.934s
user    0m0.940s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time java WithoutProxy 

real    0m0.883s
user    0m0.850s
sys     0m0.040s

$ time java WithProxy

real    0m0.937s
user    0m0.920s
sys     0m0.030s

$ time java WithoutProxy 

real    0m0.898s
user    0m0.880s
sys     0m0.030s

$ time java WithProxy

real    0m0.936s
user    0m0.950s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Slightly slower? Yes. 50x slower? No.

Now, timing the JVM is **notoriously difficult** and simple experiments like the above are necessarily suspect. But I think a 50x difference probably would have shown up.

**Edit**: I should have mentioned that the above with a very, very small number of loops posts numbers like this:

```
real    0m0.058s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.020s
```

...which gives you an idea of VM startup time in the environment. E.g., the timings above are not mostly VM startup with just a microsecond of difference in actual execution time, they're mostly execution time.

Comment: I just ran a substantially similar test, on a 6-core AMD running Ubuntu and on a 2-core Mac OS X laptop. My results are consistent with the above.

Comment: I like this answer has claims are backed up by tests.

Comment: Nice test; could you rerun it without including VM startup and JITing?

Also, the proxy in question is not just a stupid proxy, it adds considerable functionality

Comment: @Henrik: My point was that to go from a specific to generally saying "the proxy pattern is slow" is to make an un-justified leap. Some proxies will be very slow, for the reasons you capably pointed out. Some proxies will be completely transparent from a performance viewpoint once the JIT is done with them. And I see no purpose whatsoever in eliminating the JIT, it's there for a reason. I'll note the VM startup time in the question, I should have flagged that: It's massively overwhelmed by the operations in the test, but you wouldn't know why I know that.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean ot eliminating the JIT, only the overhead of compilation and the use of interpreted code before compilation has been done. But reading your code again that would likely have no noticeable since you run so many iterations

Comment: This isn't the same type of proxying as the OP mentioned in his sources. Not your fault as he didn't make it clear in the question that it was a reflective proxy he was interested in.

Comment: @Wes: "reflective proxy" as in *reflection*? Yeah, that's going to make a difference all right... :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yes reflection. java.lang.reflect.Proxy

Comment: @Wes: Ah, okay. Yeah, that's going to slow things down a bit. (Early on it slowed things down **HUGELY**, but reflection got a lot better in...what was it...1.4?)

Comment: I'm not sure which version it got better in. But yeah the example is I think a basic spring proxy. With an interface implementation to further slow things down. Although I think interfaces are a lot better now also.

Answer (score 4):

When the code has been compiled into native code, the byte array accesses would be something like 3 1 cycle instructions (as long as the source and destination data are hot in the cache and unaligned byte accesses are not penalized. YMMV depending on platform).

Adding a method call to store the four bytes will (depending on platform, but something like this) add pushing registers to the stack, a call instruction, the array access instructions,  a return instruction and popping the registers from the stack. The push/call/return/pop sequence will be added for each layer or proxy, and none of these instructions mostly don't execute in 1 cycle. If the compiler fails to inline these methods (which can happen rather easily) you'd run into a quite hefty penalty.

The proxies add functionality to convert between color depths and so on, adding extra overhead.

Also, sequential array accesses can be further optimized by the compiler (eg. turning the store operations into multiple byte access operations - up to 8 bits at a time while still taking only 1 cycle) where the proxy calls make that hard.

50x sounds a bit high, but not unreasonably so depending on the actual code.

[BufferedImage](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#a9vGG9ncPig/src/share/classes/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.java&q=bufferedimage.java&sa=N&cd=1&ct=ri) in particular adds plenty of overhead. While the proxy pattern in itself might add no discernible overhead, usage of BufferedImage probably does. Note in particular that setRGB() is synchronized, which might have severe performance implications in certain circumstances.

Comment: Or the JIT could just inline the call thus removing all overhead of the proxy.

Comment: It could, and would probably, provided it's just a proxy call with no added functionality. The compiler never inlines methods over a certain size though (can be adjusted, but I doubt it has in the askers case). And it might also not inline it for other reasons.

Comment: the only way NOT to inline the code and remove all the bounds checking is that the JIT blows up the inline cache; recently Cliff Click has addressed the issue about inlining. Having single target proxy will almost sure means full inline. http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2011-04-04-fixing-the-inlining-problem

Answer (score 3):

One place I have seen them make a difference is on code which doesn't do anything. The JVM can detect code which doesn't do anything can eliminate it.  However, using methods calls can confuse this check and the code is not eliminated.  If you compare the timing with and with out methods in such examples, you can get any ratio you wish, however if you look at how the no-methods test is going, you will see that the code has been eliminated and is going unreasonably fast. e.g. much faster than one clock cycle per loop.

---

Trivial methods are inlined, like getter and setters. They can result in no impact on performance at all.  I very much doubt the 50x times claim for a real program. I would expect closer to no-difference-what-so-ever when tested properly.